# Prove or disapprove $\pi = 3 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}(x_1^n + x_2^n)}{n+2}$ (hint needed)

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

Prove or disapprove $\pi = 3 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}(x_1^n + x_2^n)}{n+2}$,

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of $2x^2+2x+1=0$.

I've tried rewriting the series but it didn't work. There is definitely a trick but I don't see it. I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You know the solutions to that quadratic aren't real numbers, correct?

Comment: @MatthewPilling What's the problem on that? they are conjugate complex, so $x_1^n+x_2^n\in\Bbb R$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: The tag for this question is "trigonometry", not "calculus" nor "complex numbers", and $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n+2}=-\frac{z+\ln|1-z|}{z^2}$$ for $|z|<1, z\neq 0$ which makes me suspect we may need to do some complex analysis.

Comment: Why didn't rewriting the series work?  Can you show us what you did and where you got stuck?  It seems like expressing it in logarithms must work, unless, as Matthew suggests, you didn't know what to do with logs of complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing @MatthewPilling's calculation, the series (not including the $3$) is $\sum_\pm\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{z_\pm^n}{n+2}$ with $z_\pm:=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\exp\frac{\pm\pi i}{4}$, i.e.$$-\sum_\pm\left(\tfrac{z_\pm+\ln(1-z_\pm)}{z_\pm^2}+\tfrac12\right)=-\sum_\pm\left(\sqrt{2}\exp\tfrac{\mp\pi i}{4}-\tfrac{\pi}{2}\pm i\ln2+\tfrac12\right)=\pi-3.$$[Numerical analysis agrees](https://repl.it/@JosGibbons/AlarmingBitesizedList#main.py).